# How to get exact resides location of aws S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, region

This is possible to get exact resident of aws bucket location without its access or secret key?
or How to get exact aws S3 bucket location not an region?

Comment: What are you asking, here?  Buckets do not have a "location" that is more specific than the AWS region where it is provisioned -- buckets are distributed and redundant across the availability zones in the region.

Comment: I am trying to get an location instead of region

Comment: The AWS region **is** the location of the bucket.  Please provide an example of the kind of "location" value you expect to find.